# Rows and colums not in line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a pizza store in a class but when I followed a guide on YouTube both the rows and columns did not line up. How would you make sure the product name is on the same row and price, quantity and total, and line up the columns.

[image: As you see it does not line up.]

Translations if needed:

- produkt -> product
- pris -> price
- kvantitet -> quantity
- total -> total

Code:

```js
let carts = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')

let products = [{
    name: 'Vegetar Pizza',
    tag: 'vegpizza',
    price: 150,
    inCart: 0
  },
  {
    name: 'Pepperoni Pizza',
    tag: 'peppizza',
    price: 200,
    inCart: 0
  },
  {
    name: 'Hawaii Pizza',
    tag: 'hawpizza',
    price: 175,
    inCart: 0
  },
  {
    name: 'Coca Cola',
    tag: 'cocacola',
    price: 25,
    inCart: 0
  },
  {
    name: 'Rømmedressing',
    tag: 'rømmedressing',
    price: 20,
    inCart: 0
  },
  {
    name: 'Vin Flaske',
    tag: 'vinflaske',
    price: 200,
    inCart: 0
  },
  {
    name: 'Vin Glass',
    tag: 'vinglass',
    price: 50,
    inCart: 0
  },
  {
    name: 'Fanta',
    tag: 'fanta',
    price: 25,
    inCart: 0
  },
]

for (let i = 0; i < carts.length; i++) {
  carts[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    cartNumbers(products[i]);
    totalCost(products[i]);
  })
}

function cartNumbers(product) {

  let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');

  productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers);

  if (productNumbers) {
    localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', productNumbers + 1);
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', 1);
  }

  setItems(product);
}

function setItems(product) {
  let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
  cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

  if (cartItems != null) {

    if (cartItems[product.tag] == undefined) {
      cartItems = {
        ...cartItems,
        [product.tag]: product
      }
    }

    cartItems[product.tag].inCart += 1;
  } else {
    product.inCart = 1;
    cartItems = {
      [product.tag]: product
    }
  }

  localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
}

function totalCost(product) {
  let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');

  console.log(typeof cartCost);
  console.log(typeof product.price);

  if (cartCost != null) {
    cartCost = parseInt(cartCost);
    localStorage.setItem("totalCost", cartCost + product.price);
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("totalCost", product.price);
  }
}

function displayCart() {
  let cartItems = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
  cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
  let productContainer = document.querySelector(".products");
  let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');

  if (cartItems && productContainer) {
    productContainer.innerHTML = '';
    Object.values(cartItems).map(item => {
      productContainer.innerHTML += `
                <div class="product">
                    <img src="./Bilder/${item.tag}.jpg">
                    <span>${item.name}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="price">${item.price}</div>
                <div class="quantity">
                <span>${item.inCart}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="total">
                ${item.inCart * item.price},-
                </div>
                `
    });

    productContainer.innerHTML += `
                <div class="basketTotalContainer">
                    <h4 class="basketTotalTitle">
                        Total Pris
                    </h4>
                    <h4 class="basketTotal">
                        ${cartCost},-
                    </h4>
            `

  }
}

displayCart();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  /* "dytter" teksten ut fra kanten */
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  /* fjerner dotter fra lista */
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  /* mellomrom imellom feks Hjem og Meny */
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  /* fjerner understrek */
  color: #555;
}

p {
  color: #555;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  /* Gir nettsiden en bredde */
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.header .row {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.col-3 {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  min-width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.col-3 img {
  width: 100%;
}

.products-container {
  max-width: 1080px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}


/* Merker */

.Merker {
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.Merker .col-3 {
  width: 160px;
}

.Merker .col-3 img {
  width: 100% cursor: pointer;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.Merker .col-3 img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(25%);
}


/* cart items */

.products-container {
  max-width: 650px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.products-header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 650px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ff523b;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.products-title {
  width: 180px;
  height: 20px;
}

.price {
  width: 15%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.quantity {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.total {
  width: 10%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.products {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.products img {
  width: 75px;
}

.basketTotalContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.basketTotalTitle {
  width: 30%;
}

.basketTotal {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="Bilder/logo.png" width="50px">
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Hjem</a></li>
          <li><a href="Meny.html">Meny</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">Om oss</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Handlevogn</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <img src="Bilder/handlevogn.png" width="30px" height="30px">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- cart items details -->

<div class="products-container">
  <div class="products-header">
    <h5 class="product-title">Produkt</h5>
    <h5 class="price">Pris</h5>
    <h5 class="quantity">Kvantitet</h5>
    <h5 class="total">Total</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="products">

  </div>
</div>


<!-- Merker -->

<div class="Merker">
  <div class="small-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <img src="Bilder/mastercard.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <img src="Bilder/paypal.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <img src="Bilder/visa.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use a table since that is what this is?

Comment: Check out https://datatables.net/, since this is tabular data, I would do what Paulie_D said and use a table.

Comment: Quick and dirty place a `<br>` after every `<img>`, the correct way is to use a `<table>` as per Paulie_D's comment.